# CSS dropdown with caret

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make sth like this:

[image]

So far i have done:

Html:

```
<div class="panel-heading" data-toggle="collapse" href="#data2">
    <div class="heading">
        APPLICATION
    </div> 
    <span class="caret icon"></span
</div>
```

And css:

```
.panel-heading {
    padding: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.panel-heading>.heading {
    padding: 5px;
    float: left;
}

.panel-heading>.icon {
    float: right;
    background: yellow;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 5px 10px;
}

.item-detail .mini-title {
    font-size: 14pt;
    margin-bottom:5px;
    color: orange;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-top: 10px;
}

.panel-heading {
    background: #FF6600;
}

.panel-body {
    background: #EAECED;
}

.caret {
    border-left: 8px solid transparent;
    border-right: 8px solid transparent;
    border-top: 8px solid #000000;
    width:1px;
}
```

**JSFiddle result:
[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tbitowt/VN24a/6/)**

And i don't know how to handle right side of div.

I want to make a square a yellow color, and rest - orange. Caret should be black and centered in small square.

Thanks

Comment: When you say caret, do you mean arrow?

Comment: yes, exactly. As you can see, this is not working also

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot add the icon class and the caret class to the same element, because you want to use the borders to create the arrow.

Try something like this:

```
<div class="panel-heading" data-toggle="collapse" href="#data2">
    <div class="heading">
        APPLICATION
    </div> 
    <div class="icon"><div class="caret"></div></div>
</div>
```

(It works in your fiddle)

To center an element horizontally, I usually use the margins, set the left and right margins to 'auto', for example:

```
.caret { margin: 8px auto 0px auto; }
```

this will center your element and set its top margin to 8px

Comment: I don't think divs are allowed within span tags

Comment: @Pete, I think you're right, it's not allowed and not necessary even though it does work. I changed the icon span to be a div as well.

Comment: Is there a way to align caret to center automatically?

Comment: @TomaszBitowt: I added some code for horizontal aligning. (maybe it's time to read some CSS tuts ;-)